# Proof that the generalized inverse of an increasing right-continuous function is also right-continuous

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, continuity

Let $a:[0,\infty) \to [0,\infty]$ be an increasing right continuous function, and $\tau:[0,\infty) \to [0,\infty]$ be the generalized inverse, i.e. $\tau(s):=\inf\{t\ge 0: a(t)>s\}, \inf \emptyset = \infty$. Prove that $\tau$ is right continuous.

Proof. $$\{t:a(t)>s\} = \inf_{\epsilon>0} \{t:a(t)>s+\epsilon\}.$$ Therefore, $\inf\{t\ge 0: a(t)>s\} = \inf_{\epsilon>0} \inf \{t\ge 0: a(t)>s+\epsilon\}$ proving right continuity.

I have trouble figuring out why this last equality proves right-continuity. Is there a way to see this immediately? I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: I found this question two years later and am wondering if in the section $\{t:a(t)>s\} = \inf_{\epsilon>0} \{t:a(t)>s+\epsilon\}$ the $\inf$ should be changed for $\sup$ or $\cup$, since the infimum for a collection of sets is usually defined as an intersection, which in this case would be empty (or $\{\infty\}$, if allowed) for all $s$.

Comment: @Kai Daniel: Yes, strictly speaking, the first equation should replace $\inf$ with $\cup$. Then, after taking $\inf$ on both side, we can prove on the right hand $\inf(\cup _{\epsilon>0}\ldots)=\inf _{\epsilon>0}(\inf\ldots)$. That is, informally, inf of a union is inf of each union element's inf.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Substituting in the definition of $\tau(s)$, that equation is $$\tau(s)=\inf_{\epsilon>0}\tau(s+\epsilon).$$  This means for any $\delta>0$, there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $\tau(s+\epsilon)<\tau(s)+\delta$.  Since $\tau$ is increasing, this means $\tau(s)\leq\tau(t)<\tau(s)+\delta$ for any $t$ such that $s\leq t<s+\epsilon$.  This exactly verifies the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of right continuity.

Comment: With the condition of increasing, we have directly $\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}$ is $\inf_{\epsilon>0}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Proof that $\tau$ is nondecreasing.** If $s'\ge s$, then the set inclusion
$\{t:a(t)>s'\}\subset\{t:a(t)>s\}$ implies
$$\tau(s'):=\inf\{t:a(t)>s'\}\ge\inf\{t:a(t)>s\}=:\tau(s).\tag1$$

---

**Proof that $\tau$ is right continuous.** For given $s$, suppose $t$ is such that $a(t)>s$. Then there exists $\delta>0$ such that $a(t)>s+\delta$. So
$$t\ge \inf\{t:a(t)>s+\delta\}=:\tau(s+\delta)\ge\inf_{\delta >0}\tau(s+\delta),\tag2$$
so the RHS of (2) is a lower bound for $\{t: a(t)>s\}$. Therefore
$$\inf_{\delta>0}\tau(s+\delta)\le \inf\{t: a(t)>s\}=:\tau(s).\tag3$$
Let $\epsilon>0$. Inequality (3) says there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\tau(s+\delta)<\tau(s)+\epsilon$. If $s\le s'<s+\delta$ then
$$\tau(s)\stackrel{(1)}\le\tau(s')\stackrel{(1)}\le\tau(s+\delta)<\tau(s)+\epsilon;$$ this means that $\tau$ is right continuous at $s$.

---

Note that these properties follow from the condition $a(t)>s$ and the definition of infimum. Nowhere do we use the assumption that $a$ is increasing or right-continuous.

Comment: I have really aprreciated your answer! So, the functional inverse defined as $\tau(s):=\inf\{t\ge 0: a(t)>s\}$ is increasing and right-continuous whatever the form of $a:[0,\infty) \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ ? I would agree, but I am now wondering why statements on the right-continuity of $\tau$ so often make reference to the right-continuity of $a$.

Comment: @Fran712 I think most treatments of the generalized inverse assume that $a$ is increasing and right-continuous (and also non-negative) because this is the most common context where the inverse is a useful quantity; we usually are starting with $a$ being a cumulative distribution function.

Comment: I guess so too, thanks for sharing your view.