# Understanding why a generalized inverse of a right-continuous function is right-continuous

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to prove that the generalized iniverse $g^- (s) =\inf_t \{t:a(t)>s\}$  of a bounded from below, nondecreasing and right-continuous function is right-continuous.

There is a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2597227/proof-that-the-generalized-inverse-of-an-increasing-right-continuous-function-is) which I'm not able to follow since I'm not sure what $\{t:a(t)>s\} = \inf_{\epsilon>0} \{t:a(t)>s+\epsilon\} $ means - though I would guess it means something like $\{t:a(t)>s\} = \{t:a(t)>s+\epsilon\}$ where $\epsilon $ is the greates lower bound of the set of real numbers $\eta \ge 0 $ such that for every $t $ in the left hand side $a(t)>\eta $. But I'm not able do do the rest of the proof using this.

Instead I tried the following: For any $s$ there are two cases: either $a(t) $ atains the value $s $ at some point $t_0$ or it "jumps past it". In the later case there exists an $\epsilon>0 $ such that $f $ also "jumps past" $s+ \epsilon $ in which case we have $\{t:a(t)>s\}=\{t:a(t)>s +\epsilon \}$ meaning that the generalized inverse $g^- $ is constant on $[y,y+\epsilon) $ and thus certainly right-continuous at $y $.

> Is there an intuitive way to reason from the following two pictures, the first of a function $a(t)$ and the second of it's generalized invers $g^-(s)$, that from the conditions on $a $ follows the right-continuity of $g^- $ - and of course supply the abstract solution.?

[image: graph of a(t)]
[image: graph of g^-]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

1. Prove $\{t:a(t)>s\}=\bigcup\limits_{\epsilon>0}\{t:a(t)>s+\epsilon\}$.
2. Take $\inf$ on both sides, we have $\inf\{t:a(t)>s\}=\inf\bigl[\bigcup\limits_{\epsilon>0}\{t:a(t)>s+\epsilon\}\bigr]$.
3. We can prove that $\inf\bigl(\bigcup\limits_{\epsilon>0}\ldots\bigr)=\inf\limits_{\epsilon>0}(\inf\ldots)$. That is, informally, inf of a union is inf of each union element's inf. A similar proof of this equality can be seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3371939/prove-the-equality-inf-zy-inf-e-z-inf-cup-zye-z-e-z-xfxz?rq=1).
4. So, we have $\inf\{t:a(t)>s\}=\inf\limits_{\epsilon>0}\bigl[\inf\{t:a(t)>s+\epsilon\}\bigr]$, which is exactly $g^-(s)=\inf\limits_{\epsilon>0}g^-(s+\epsilon)$.
5. Prove that $g^-(s)$ is increasing.
6. When a function is increasing, its right limit is just the $\inf$ of the function values on the right, i.e., informally, $\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to0^+}$ is $\inf\limits_{\epsilon>0}$. Applying this to the right side of 4., we have $g^-(s)=\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to0^+}g^-(s+\epsilon)$, which is just the right-continuity.