# Prove the equality $\inf_{z>y} \inf E_z=\inf \cup_{z>y}E_z, \ E_z:=\{x:f(x)>z\}$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

> I would like to prove the equality given in the title, that is 
>   $$\inf_{z>y} \inf E_z=\inf \bigcup_{z>y}E_z, \ E_z:=\{x\in \mathbb{R } :f(x)>z\}$$

I don't think any more information is needed but for a reference this is a step in a proof that the generalized inverse of (any) real-valued function is right-continous and the proof is given in Proposition 4.2 in the [following](https://hal-mines-paristech.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01255512/file/Report-GeneralizedInverse-partI.pdf) dokument (on page 10).

> What would be the approach to prove the equality?

Particularly the infimum of the infimum of the left hand side makes me a bit confused. But I suppose it is means that for every $z $ we get a greates lower bound on $E_z $ and we collect all of those greatest lower bound into a set of which we then takes the greatest lower bound?

Most grateful for any help provided!

Comment: You have written the definition of $E_z$ wrongly.

Comment: Thanks! Now corrected!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the question are not specified the domain and the range of the function $f$. I guess you mean that $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, whereas in  the  proof of Proposition 4.2 deal with $f:\bar{\Bbb R}\to\bar{\Bbb R}$. But we don’t need to specify this,  we don’t need to know what are $E_z$. It suffice to know that they are non-empty subsets of a linearly ordered space $L$ such that each non-empty open subset $E\subset L$ has $\inf E\in L$. Remark that both $\Bbb R$ and $\bar{\Bbb R}$ satisfy this condition.

> $\inf_{z>y} \inf E_z=\inf \bigcup_{z>y}E_z$

Put $i_1=\inf_{z>y} \inf E_z $ and $i_2=\inf \bigcup_{z>y}E_z $. Pick any $z>y$. Since $i_2\le x$ for each $x\in E_z$, $i_2\le\inf E_z$. Since this holds for each $z>y$, $i_2\le  \inf_{z>y} \inf E_z=i_1$. Now pick any $x\in \bigcup_{z>y}E_z$. Then $x\in E_z$ for some $z>y$. So $i_1\le\inf E_z\le x$. Since this holds for each   $x\in \bigcup_{z>y}E_z$, $i_1\le\inf \bigcup_{z>y}E_z=i_2$.